# Visualization of Eratosthenes’ sieve

Tags: prime-numbers, visualization

In otherwise great paper on prime numbers, I found following visualization of Eratosthenes’ sieve:

[image]

I found it somewhat scary and confusing.

Is there any better visualization of Eratosthenes’ sieve out there?

Comment: Try to find an animation. A fixed image is terrible for representing an algorithm.

Comment: A nice feature of this visualization is that it shows the pattern of multiples of each prime--including numbers that are multiples of more than one prime. You don't get the full effect of this when each number has to be marked in just one way, even if you use a different color for each prime. But it does result in a very cluttered diagram.

Comment: All primes except for $2$ and $3$ are of the form $6n\pm1$. Hence the $2\times2=4$ columns in the table of width $12$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Wikipedia. [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes):

[image]

Comment: This animation also nicely illustrates the fact that, to find all the primes up to some maximum $n$, you only need to sieve out multiples of primes less than $\sqrt n$. (Here, $n = 120 < 11^2 = 121$, so the only primes whose multiples need to be sieved out are 2, 3, 5 and 7.) After that, all the remaining unsieved numbers will be primes.

Comment: This visualization is a bit inconsistent in the way it deals with multi-factor numbers (i.e., numbers with two or more distinct factors). 

In some cases the larger factor overrides the smaller one (for example 30 is painted red, then green then red) in other cases, the smaller factor determines the final color (For example 6 remains red although it has a green factor, 3)

Comment: Update: I looked at the source in Wikipedia, and this visualization "includes an optimization of starting from prime's square"

Answer (score 5):

I definitely agree that animation and interactivity would be helpful in this case.

However, I just found three static visualizations similar to the one from the question, but in my opinion significantly better:

[image]

[image]

[image]